# Ionic v1 Build Failed in android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I have an ionic v1 app, when I tried to produce apk using `ionic cordova build android` it failed to build the app.

[image: error msg]

I already change the `DistibutionURL on my .js file to 4.xx` but every time I build the apps it detects that I have gradle 3.xx. Why is this?

Comment: your app correctly work on web browser or not

Comment: Please copy-paste the error messages instead of posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to remove all installed platforms and delete plugin and platform folder. Re-add platform. Thanks to @Guillem Perez.

Answer (score 0):

You edited the correct file? It's not a js file.

*ionic-project/platforms/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*

You will see

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Change to

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

If this doesn't work try to install another cordova android platform:

> cordova platform rm android
>
> cordova platform add android@7.1.1

Or with 7.0.0 version, I recommend the 6.3.0 for legacy compatible.

Comment: Can I contact you on facebook? Please? Im really stuck

Comment: I removed android platform and add android platform 6.3.0 and I got a new error `Execution failed for task: "transformClassesWithDexForDebug"`